# Avoid redudant authorization check for all http requests

Tags: java, http, request

I'm working on a web application using React on the frontend and Java on the backend. From the frontend, I call different resources from the backend, where I have various classes providing `@GET` methods.

For every method, I'm always using the same check to determine if the user is authorized based on their session ID. That's a very repetitive way to accomplish this. This is especially true when creating a new `@GET` method, as I have to always remember to add this `isUserAuthorized` check.

My first thought was using an `abstract` class for the resources to centralize some of the code, but here I'd still have to add the check to each method.

Is there a way I can implement the authorization check for *all* HTTP requests, without needing to repeat this code?

Comment: Have you tried something? if yes post your code here please.

Comment: What Java server and frameworks are you using on the backend to serve up your web services?